# To find max salary using friend function of a class having employee details(name,ID, position,salary) and print max salary details

Tags: c++, class, oop, friend-function

```
#include <iostream.h>

#include <conio.h>

class Employee{
    int Id;

    string Name;
    string Post;        

  public:

  long int Salary;

    void GetDetails();
    void DisplayDetails();
friend void MaxSalary();

};

void Employee::GetDetails(){

    cout << "\nEnter Employee Id : ";       
    cin >> Id;      
    cout << "\nEnter Employee Name : ";     
    cin.ignore();       
    getline(cin,Name);      
    cout << "\nEnter Employee Post : ";     
    cin.ignore();       
    getline(cin,Post);      
    cout << "\nEnter Employee Salary : ";       
    cin >> Salary;

}

void Employee::DisplayDetails(){
    
    cout << "\nEmployee Id : " << Id;       
    cout << "\nEmployee Name : " << Name;       
    cout << "\nEmployee Post : " << Post;       
    cout << "\nEmployee Salary : " << Salary;

}


void MaxSalary(Employee a[], int x){
    
    long int max;
    
    for(int j=0; j<x; j++){         
        if(a[j].Salary>a[j+1].Salary)           
            max=a[j].Salary;    
    }
    
    cout<<"Maximum Salary = "<<max<<endl;

}


int main()    
{
    
    int n, i;       
    cout<<"Enter Number of Employees : ";    
    cin>>n;     
    Employee E[n];      
    cout<<"\n\n----------ENTER DETAILS OF EMPLOYEES----------\n\n";  

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){           
        cout<<"\n\n    Enter details of Employee "<<i+1<<endl;          
        E[i].GetDetails();      
    }
    
    cout<<"\n\n----------DETAILS OF EMPLOYEES----------\n\n";
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){       
         cout<<"\n\n    Details of Employee "<<i+1<<endl;
         E[i].DisplayDetails();    
    }    
    
    MaxSalary(E[n], n );
            
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to [edit] your post. As it is, it deters users from answering.

Comment: @KyleWang, I appreciate your effort, but in this case it teaches the wrong lesson that only the formatting of this post is a problem.

Comment: Please provide [mre] and edit the  post accordingly

Comment: This question lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered. "Do <something>. Here is my code." is not a question.

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of the salaries of all the objects?

Comment: Using C arrays in C++ is usually not a good idea,. Using them like you did is wrong in at least three ways. If you would ask an actual question I could check whether those mistakes cause your problem or answer your question.

Comment: Arch Issue: why should the Employee class be "able" to calculate such max op?? and where is ***MaxSalary(Employee n[], int n )*** defined?

Comment: Maybe this would be better at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), since there is not a real question but a lot of things that could be changed to make it better C++ code.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy The fact that this question is asked and the code, both indicate that the code is not doing what it is supposed to do. It is hence off-topic for code-review.

Answer (score 0):

**There are lots of defects in the given code:**

1. The variable length arrays (VLAs) are not allowed in C++. In other words, the syntax:

   ```
   cin >> x;
   Employee emp[x];
   ```

   is invalid. Note that C99 is an exception in this case.
2. In the For loop of `MaxSalary()`, `a[j + 1]` is given, it will access out-of-bounds array, which invokes an undefined behavior.
3. Declaring a variable in a class as public breaks the rule of OOP:

   ```
   public:
     long int Salary; // Not a good idea
   ```
4. You do not need to pass `[n]` as the function argument:

   ```
   MaxSalary(E[n], n);
   ```

---

**The refined code would look like:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

// Using this statement in order to reduce the spam of 'std::' here
using namespace std;

class Employee {
  int ID;
  string name;
  string post;
  long int salary;

public:
  Employee() {}
  // Initializing the class object
  void initEmployee(int id, string varName, string varPost, long sal) {
    ID = id,        \
    name = varName, \
    post = varPost, \
    salary = sal;
  }
  // 'salary' getter
  long getSalary() {
    return salary;
  }

  // The friend function
  friend void maxSalary(vector<Employee> data) {
    int max = 0;

    for (size_t i{1}, len = data.size(); i < len; i++)
      // Comparison
      if (data[i].getSalary() > data[i - 1].getSalary())
        max = data[i].getSalary();

    // After the loop execution, prints the maximum salary
    std::cout << "Maximum salary: " << max << endl;
  }
};

int main(void) {
  int total;

  cout << "Enter the total number of employees: ";
  cin >> total;

  vector<Employee> emp(total);

  for (int i{}; i < total; i++) {
    // Temporary variables to store data in each iteration
    Employee temp;
    string tempName;
    string tempPost;
    int tempID;
    long int tempSal;

    cout << "Name of the employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
    getline(cin, tempName);

    // Clearing the 'cin' in order to prevent the getline skips
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "Post of the employee: ";
    getline(cin, tempPost);

    cout << "Employee ID: ";
    cin >> tempID;

    cout << "Total salary: ";
    cin >> tempSal;

    // Initializing the temporary object
    temp.initEmployee(tempID, tempName, tempPost, tempSal);
    // Pushing the object into the main vector
    emp.push_back(temp);
  }

  // Comparing the vector elements (note: it is a friend function)
  maxSalary(emp);

  return 0;
}
```

**As a test case:**

```
Enter the total number of employees: 2 // Number of employees
Name of the employee 1: John Doe       // Employee 1
Post of the employee: Manager
Employee ID: 100
Total salary: 15000
Name of the employee 2: Max Ville      // Employee 2
Post of the employee: Assitant Manager
Employee ID: 102
Total salary: 50000
Maximum salary: 50000    // Maximum salary
```

Comment: what if I want to display the details of employee whose salary is max along with his/her salary